# Multiple errors on capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, capistrano, bundler

Hi so I'm trying to deploy using Capistrano to a server, on the server I have `rails` `bundler` and everything else installed, however, here is the Capistrano log

https://gist.github.com/benbagley/cf8233aaa0c5adac0fa09f2194fc6890

Here is the trimmed down version of just the errors:

```
00:27 deploy:assets:precompile
      01 RBENV_ROOT=/home/poladmin/.rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.5.1 /home/poladmin/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec rake assets:precompile
      01 rake aborted!
      01 Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
      01
      01 Caused by:
      01 LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
      01 /home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
      01 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
#<Thread:0x000056102ca202a0@/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from /home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/home/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/sshkit-1.16.1/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as poladmin@196.28.51.162: rake exit status: 1 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as poladmin@196.28.51.162: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as poladmin@196.28.51.162: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find rake-12.3.1 in any of the sources
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/home/poladmin/poetry_out_loud_v2/releases/20180629214135/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

It's in a gist due to its size.

Here is the gem list on the server

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actioncable (5.2.0)
actionmailer (5.2.0)
actionpack (5.2.0)
actionview (5.2.0)
activejob (5.2.0)
activemodel (5.2.0)
activerecord (5.2.0)
activestorage (5.2.0)
activesupport (5.2.0)
arel (9.0.0)
bigdecimal (default: 1.3.4)
builder (3.2.3)
bundler (1.16.2)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
crass (1.0.4)
csv (default: 1.0.0)
date (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.2.0)
erubi (1.7.1)
etc (default: 1.0.0)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.0.2)
globalid (0.4.1)
i18n (1.0.1)
io-console (default: 0.4.6)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
loofah (2.2.2)
mail (2.7.0)
marcel (0.3.2)
method_source (0.9.0)
mimemagic (0.3.2)
mini_mime (1.0.0)
mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
minitest (5.10.3)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nio4r (2.3.1)
nokogiri (1.8.3)
openssl (default: 2.1.0)
power_assert (1.1.1)
psych (default: 3.0.2)
rack (2.0.5)
rack-test (1.0.0)
rails (5.2.0)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.4)
railties (5.2.0)
rake (12.3.0)
rdoc (default: 6.0.1)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
sprockets (3.7.2)
sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
stringio (default: 0.0.1)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
test-unit (3.2.7)
thor (0.20.0)
thread_safe (0.3.6)
tzinfo (1.2.5)
webrick (default: 1.4.2)
websocket-driver (0.7.0)
websocket-extensions (0.1.3)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

Comment: If it's too big to post here in its entirety, trim it down. External links don't make it any easier for us to read through and figure out what's going on.

Comment: Ok I've added a trimmed down version of the output just showing the errors @tadman

Comment: Looks like `rake` 12.3.1 is missing. You have 12.3.0 in your `Gemfile`. Would getting those synced up to the latest help?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Gemfile in your project you can try add bundle install into one of the deploy steps and have that install all the required ruby gems. Also as the rake version is mismatching you need to update the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to make it matches the required version first.